# Remove blocks for every action in a controller

Tags: magento

Hello guys i have created a controller. I want every action in this controller that is rendering layout to exclude header and footer. Is it possible to this via the xml.

```
<adminhtml_trips_index>
    <remove name="header" />
    <remove name="menu" />
    <remove name="footer" />
```

without doing this for each action?

Also is there some event observer like _beforeRenderLayout.

The only solution i have at the moment is to invoke my custom made exclude_redundant_blocks() function, after $this->loadLayout() in every action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not override the `loadLayout` method in your own controller and exclude the blocks after that instead of doing it in every action?

Something like this:

```
public function loadLayout($ids=null, $generateBlocks=true, $generateXml=true)
{
    parent::loadLayout($ids, $generateBlocks, $generateXml);
    //remove blocks here
    return $this;
}
```

Or an other way would be to create a customer layout handle that removes the unwanted blocks

```
<custom_handle>
    <remove name="header" />
    <remove name="menu" />
    <remove name="footer" />
</custom_handle>
```

Then load that handle in each action.
again rewrite the loadLayout method and make it look like this

```
public function loadLayout($ids=null, $generateBlocks=true, $generateXml=true)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('custom_handle')
    return parent::loadLayout($ids, $generateBlocks, $generateXml);
}
```

the code above is untested, but in theory it should work.

Comment: This is indeed the tidiest method. I would do the same

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why i didn't think of overriding  the loadLayout. Also the loading of handle is very good pattern i didn't know of.